# How to change id of datatable?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have some websocket listening code that already do good things when receiveing some events.

I now need to force reloading of datatable ONLY if I am in a specific page.

I'd like to specify the id the of the datatable iteself (or add a data-, or add a class) in the List Operation, so i can check presence and do specific things only if user is watching the specific class

How can I customize the datatable in the List Operation (without ovverride the .blade.php) to add id, class or data- to the datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you can't. But maybe you can:

(A) force reload the datatable only if on the correct *route*;

(B) force reload the datatable if something is present in the DOM; and you can add things to the page using [widgets](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-widgets);